# Blender Background in Docker Container Evee Rendering

Tags: docker, blender, xserver

What i am trying to do is run blender evee rendering in a docker container. What i have working is run that on a remote linux machine. for that i had to install the Nvidia/Cuda and XServer. After that I could run

Xorg :1 &
sleep 5
DISPLAY=:1.0 blender/blender -b lighting_evee_new.blend -P lighting_evee_new.py

the sleep is just there to give the XServer time to start up.

Now I am trying to do the same in a Docker Container. The Nvidia/Cuda stuff is simple, but I am lost with the XServer part.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this will help https://dis.co/blog/build-a-blender-docker-container-for-distributing-rendering/

Answer (score -1):

I did similar thing but I used google remote desktop to trick blender to think there is a screen attached

Here is how I did it https://www.cryptolabs.co.za/2020/04/30/how-to-rendering-blender-eevee-on-a-headless-system/

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).